# Unable to link duma library

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors

I am trying to use DUMA (http://duma.sourceforge.net/) but cannot seem to properly link it into my code.  Here is my makefile:

```
CXX := /home/projects/gcc/482/bin/c++

CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -I/home/duma_2_5_15/
LDFLAGS := -L/home/duma_2_5_15/ -lduma

#CXX_DEPEND := -MMD -MF .d.$(subst .cc,,$*) -MP -MT $@
CXX_DEPEND :=

define compile-c++-and-emit-deps
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXX_DEPEND) -c $< -o $@
endef

%.o : %.cc
    $(compile-c++-and-emit-deps)

srcs := $(wildcard *.cc)
objs := $(srcs:.cc=.o)
deps := $srcs:%.cc=.d.%)

default: test

test: $(objs)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(objs)

#-include $(deps)
```

when I run "make", I receive the following errors:

```
> make
/home/projects/gcc/482/bin/c++ -L/home/duma_2_5_15/ -lduma -o test main.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x193c): undefined reference to `_duma_malloc'
main.cc:(.text+0x19f8): undefined reference to `_duma_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Am I not linking duma properly?  My main.cc file does include the following header:

```
#include "duma.h"
```

I did read the following note on the DUMA homepage:

Some systems will require special arguments to the linker to assure that you
are using the DUMA malloc() and not the one from your C library.

However I'm not sure how to proceed from here.  This is running on Linux 2.6.18-308.el5.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to my own question.  Note the "-lduma" addition on the second to last line of code at the bottom.  This was all I had to add to make it link properly.

```
CXX := /home/projects/gcc/482/bin/c++

CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -I/home/duma_2_5_15/
LDFLAGS := -L/home/duma_2_5_15/ -lduma

#CXX_DEPEND := -MMD -MF .d.$(subst .cc,,$*) -MP -MT $@
CXX_DEPEND :=

define compile-c++-and-emit-deps
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXX_DEPEND) -c $< -o $@
endef

%.o : %.cc
    $(compile-c++-and-emit-deps)

srcs := $(wildcard *.cc)
objs := $(srcs:.cc=.o)
deps := $srcs:%.cc=.d.%)

default: test

test: $(objs)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(objs) -lduma

#-include $(deps)
```